# kerberos ticket error on chrome browser while accessing active resource manager UI / JMX

Tags: google-chrome, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, kerberos, resourcemanager

Good day.

I have enabled kerberos on my HDP cluster.
I am trying to access active resource manager UI / JMX link via yarn on ambari.
but unable to open it in chrome.

This is the error -

```
HTTP ERROR 403
Problem accessing /cluster. Reason:

    GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
Powered by Jetty://
```

How can I resolve this issue.
Is there anyway, i can enable ticket on chrome browser.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough information here.  What is the SPN of the resource?  Does it work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Have you researched anything on SPNEGO Auth in Chrome?